# Any faster travelling method between Mingan National Park and Gaspésie?

Tags: quebec

Focussed on (free, only for 2017) National Parks, my grandparents wish to travel to Mingan National Park directly from Gaspé. Is there any method more direct and faster than:

1. [Air Canada's flight YGP-YQB-YZV (Sept-Îles)](https://www.kayak.com/flights/YGP-YZV/2017-10-02) =
   [90 m (check-in deadline)](https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/plan/check-in-information/check-in-and-boarding-times.html) + 3 h 30 m (flight time) + [2 h 2 m](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Sept-Iles,+QC/Mingan,+QC/@49.7297433,-66.5570665,8.09z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4c91de48efd48999:0xe842563acc1952b6!2m2!1d-66.375792!2d50.2132968!1m5!1m1!1s0x4c850d03e6348c83:0x1c9194573345042b!2m2!1d-64.023161!2d50.291457!3e0) (YZV-Mingan) ?
2. driving + [Matane-Godbout ferry](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mingan+Archipelago+National+Park+Reserve,+Rue+de+la+Digue,+Havre-Saint-Pierre,+QC/Gasp%C3%A9,+QC/@48.5667983,-66.0573575,7z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x4c8458b016f5ec23:0x6457560f8a660bcd!2m2!1d-63.5532251!2d50.225861!1m5!1m1!1s0x4c9bbf23b75f9eab:0x4971fdae95f10155!2m2!1d-64.4869017!2d48.8316351) = 10 h 38 m ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it would be a better/faster method, but you can also take a plane or a boat to Havre-Saint-Pierre which is much closer to Mingan. Sadly, there are no boat crossing directly from Gaspé. You have to at least go to Matane or Rimouski. In Rimouski, you could take a boat to Mingan, but it will probably take more time than by car.

One important thing to know, however, is to be prepared. Mingan is not a very popular touristic destination (despite its beauty). Therefore, you should reserve in advance the boat arrangement and your accommodations. At Mingan, you are close to the wild Quebec.